# Testng-Xslt reports are not getting generated

Tags: maven, selenium, pom.xml

I have gone through many posts and blogs but couldn't generate reportng or testng-xslt reports via maven. Finally I have got this tutorial but no luck. I cant understand what am I missing. 
Here's what I have tried : It successfully generates the surefire reports in the target folder but does"nt create(generate reports) a directory for reportng reports.Following is my Pom.xml file.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>tiger</groupId>
  <artifactId>SampleProject</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>SampleProject</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.45.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.6</version>
        </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.18.1</version>

          <configuration>
          <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
          </suiteXmlFiles>
        </configuration>

        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
  <reporting>
              <plugins>
                     <!-- TestNG-xslt related configuration. -->
                     <plugin>
                           <groupId>org.reportyng</groupId>
                           <artifactId>reporty-ng</artifactId>
                           <version>1.2</version>
                           <configuration>
                                  <!-- Output directory for the testng xslt report -->
                                  <outputDir>/target/testng-xslt-report</outputDir>
                                  <sortTestCaseLinks>true</sortTestCaseLinks>
                                   <testDetailsFilter>FAIL,SKIP,PASS,CONF,BY_CLASS</testDetailsFilter>
                                  <showRuntimeTotals>true</showRuntimeTotals>
                           </configuration>
                     </plugin>
              </plugins>
       </reporting>


</project>
```

Comment: what maven goal did you run?

Comment: I ran mvn clean and then mvn install

Comment: xslt report would be generated when you run your test cases so to run your tests you need to run command `mvn test`. try this command.

Comment: I did tried mvn test but its the same , didnt get the xslt report. Do i have to add any jars other than the dependency in pom?

Comment: whats the output you are getting in console after running `mvn test`

Comment: I ran it from cmd and it gave this :Surefire report directory: C:\Users\Shashank_bisht\workspace\SampleProject\target\surefire-reports. Surefire reports being created but not xslt.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like they have removed `reporty-ng` plugin from `maven repository`, so you may not be able to generate xslt report directly through maven.

If you want to generate `XSLT` reports you can take help of [Ant XSLT](http://software-testing-tutorials-automation.blogspot.in/2014/08/ant-generate-xslt-reports-in-selenium.html)

Comment: But sources was saved: https://github.com/prash-akella/reporty-ng So you are able to compile and use it if you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like the default report for any reasons, you can write your own one by implementing [IReporter](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/IReporter.html): 
http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#logging

Comment: I have used reportNg

Comment: I have switched to using reportNG reports

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using below

```
<pluginRepositories>
              <pluginRepository>
                     <id>reporty-ng</id>
                     <url>https://github.com/cosminaru/reporty-      ng/raw/master/dist/maven</url>
```

Url is not working. They have removed it from that URL. However, I think you can use this URL   https://github.com/prashanth-sams/testng-xslt-1.1.2/tree/master/src/main/java/org/testng/xslt/mavenplugin  . I haven't tried it though.

You can download it from. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B5v_nInLNoquV1p5YWtHc3lkUkU